# At subclass Compilation Error: Unreachable catch block for CloneNotSupportedException

Tags: java, exception, overriding

In `SuperClass`, When I override `clone()` method then there is no problem.

```
public class SuperClass implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I override `clone()` method in my `SubClass` by doing exactly same (**Copy and Paste** `clone()` method from super class)  it's showing compilation error

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation Error in `SubClasss` at the line containing `catch`:

> Unreachable catch block for CloneNotSupportedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Again, If I remove the method `clone()` from `SuperClass` then `SubClass` wont show any error.

Where is the gap of my understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `SuperClass`'s `clone` catches `CloneNotSupportedException` and doesn't throw it, `SubClass` doesn't have to catch it, since it can never be thrown by the try block of `SubClass`'s `clone()`.

When you remove `clone()` from `SuperClass`, `SubClass` now calls `Object`'s `clone()` which has a `throws CloneNotSupportedException` clause. Therefore you have to catch that exception (or add a `throws CloneNotSupportedException` to your method).

Comment: Thanks **Eran**. Now I'm feeling shame that how I have confused just with ``super`` keyword and **Compile-Time Exception**.

Comment: Sometimes it happens. We will quickly realize our simple mistakes.